# "Argument of Type Incompatible" from Inherited Class

Tags: c++, error-handling, arguments

In the case of the code below, the error being presented is as follows:

> Argument of type "ThatThingThatUsesExceptions::HereBeTheError *" is not compatible with parameter of type "Exception *"

This is the full error as shown from my actual code:

> (active)   E0167   argument of type "Input::ErrorNoPinSet *" is incompatible with parameter of type "Exception *"  AddingOOP   c:\MyFilePathToMyRepoDir\DroneSoftware\ArduinoBasedCode\AddingOOP\Input.cpp 17

I'm writing a large amount of code for a drone, and as such much of the code will run on microcontrollers, which unfortunately don't usually have the capability of using try-catch error handling. I'm attempting to implement it in what is probably a very hack-y way, but I'm running into somewhat of a problem.

This is an extremely simplified version of what's happening:

```cpp
class Exception
{
public:
    static void eThrowException(Exception* error)
    {
        Serial.println(error->what());
    }

    virtual const char* what();
};

class ThingThatUsesTheExceptions
{
private:
    struct HereBeTheError : public Exception { const char* what() { return "Yarrrrr me matey"; } };

protected:
    void cFunctionThatTriggersAnError()
    {
        Exception::eThrowException(&HereBeTheError()); //This is where the error occurs.
    }
};
```

I should mention that all of these are split into their own files. Exception.h holds the declarations, Exception.cpp holds the definitions, and the same with ThatThingThatUsesExceptions. I'm not sure why the error is throwing. I've tried it with MANY different combinations, passing into eThrowException the following combinations:

```cpp
&HereBeTheError()
*HereBeTheError()
new HereBeTheError()
HereBeTheError()
*new HereBeTheError()
&new HereBeTheError()
```

I've pretty much tried everything I can think of, including several things that seemed stupid, but I was out of options and decided to try all the options I could think of.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: This shall yields a linking error, as you declare `virtual const char* what();` in class `Exception` without definition, when I set it to pure virtual it worked using G++ 7.2

Answer (score 0):

With g++ the error message is a little bit less ambiguous:

```
prog.cpp:22:52: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
```

The alternative `new HereBeTheError()` would compile, but would result in a memory leak.

A working way to do it would be to use a local variable:

```
    HereBeTheError a;
    Exception::eThrowException(&a); //This works
```

You could also go for passing argument by reference instead of by pointer.  Then you are allowed to pass a temporary, under the condition that it's a const reference ([demo](https://ideone.com/hoZ8lo)).